# How can i create recursively child directories on my ftp server untill done all directories and directories with capital chars?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

This is the method i'm using to create directory on my ftp server.

```
public void createDirectory(string newDirectory)
        {
            try
            {
                string FtpHost = f.Host + "/" + newDirectory;
                if (!FtpHost.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                    FtpHost = "ftp://" + FtpHost;
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FtpHost);
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                ftpResponse1 = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                ftpResponse1.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }
```

The problem and why i need to make recursive loop is for example this case:

If in the textBox i type a directory like this: c/1/2/3/4/5 and on my ftp server child/sub directories under c 1/2/3/4 not exist not created yet before it will throw exception. But if i manualy type in the textBox once c/1 it will create the directory fine. Then i type c/1/2 will create it fine. Then i type c/1/2/3 will create fine. Then i type c/1/2/3/4 will create fine. Then if type or paste to the textBox c/1/2/3/4/5 it will create it fine since all the directories 1/2/3/4 already exist so it will create directory 5 not problems.

For some reason it dosen't understand or know to create the child/sub directories if some of them not exist yet already. It will not create c/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 it will not create directory 8 if 1/2/3/4/5/6/7 already created.

That's why i need to make some loop recursive that will also check if the directories exist on my server and then to create them if not for example: c/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8
The loop should check if c/1 exist if not create then create c/1/2 then c/1/2/3 untill c/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 and in case the directories c/1/2/3/4/5/6 already exist but i typed c/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 the loop should find that untill 6 the directories exist already so to create only /7/8

The exception in in all cases there was exception is the same but i'm sure this is the problem that i need to make somehow recursive loop that also will check if the child/sub directories already exist.

WebException

The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at FTP_ProgressBar.FtpProgress.createDirectory(String newDirectory) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\FtpProgress.cs:line 295
  InnerException:
```

Line 295 is:

```
ftpResponse1 = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: 1. some FTP servers may be case sensitive (eg. hosted on a *nix OS) others maybe case sensitive but case preserving (eg. Windows). In the latter case "/a/B/c" and "/a/b/c" are the same. Also, 2, you are right: you cannot assume creating a folder will create all intermediate folders: you need to create each one in the path incrementally.

Comment: What happens (record and include the session in the Q) when you do these operations in an interactive command line FTP session (*not a GUI tool*)? (If you're going to be doing non-trivial FTP operations start by learning FTP and how your target servers react to different commands in different circumstances.)

Comment: It is very hard to follow your comments: 1. Add information to the question where it can be shown clearly (everything inline in the one paragraph of a comment is too hard to follow). 2. include the state of the FTP server before (eg. what folder exists), and the exception's type and message. TL;DR: make the question easy to answer.

Comment: Please don't do a `catch (Exception ex)` as it is a bad practice that leads to buggy code. You should only catch specific exceptions that you can handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split the directory name with `/` and then create hierarchical directory individually.

```
string[] folderArray = directory.Split('/');
string folderName = "";
for (int i = 0; i < folderArray.Length; i++)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderArray[i]))
    {
        folderName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) ? folderArray[i] : folderName + "/" + folderArray[i];
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress + "/" + folderName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var test = response.ToString();
    }
}
```